# db2 backup image name

Tags: db2, rdbms, restore, back, db2-luw

In deferent instances of db2 I got different image name.

The biggest part
after command "backup database sample to /tmp/1"
returned file

/tmp/1/SAMPLE.0.DB2.NODE0000.CATN0000.20240421171717.001

but exist one more variant
after command "backup database sample to /tmp/1"

returned file

/tmp/1/SAMPLE.0/DB2/NODE0000/CATN0000/20240421/171717.001

what setting controls this?

Answer (score 0):

Please tag all your Db2-questions with the correct rdbms tag, in this case db2-luw, and it also helps if you specify the exact version of the Db2-server. For Db2-LUW, you can give the plain text output of the `db2level` command on the server.

The command `backup database` for Db2-LUW will create image(s) in locations whose root part(s) you can specify.

For backups to locally-addressable file-systems (as distinct from remote/cloud-storage), the full path and filename will vary according to three factors (1) the nature of your Db2-server installation as well, single-node, multiple-node, number of instances on the host, number of databases in the instance etc, (2) the command line arguments given to `backup database` command, and (3) run time information such as the timestamp.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-backup-database) for your Db2-LUW version and study the expected behaviour.

If you find more image files with unexpected names or paths , it is more likely the result of a manual error, or misunderstanding of actual Db2 behaviour.

If in doubt, try to recreate and compare actual behaviour to the expected behaviour for your Db2-server version as specified in the documentation.

Remember that when you use `db2 restore database` and you supply a disk based image, then the path must match the argument given to the matching `db2 backup database` command for the **same** Db2-instance (and the directory tree beneath it should also match).  If you are moving databases between difference Db2-instances (.e.g on different real or virtual hosts, or between different Db2-instances on the same hostname), then different rules apply, and usually you then want to perform a redirected restore. Refer to the documentation for details.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I changed tags
I provide more information
I use sample db
I have instance on server which create backup 
/tmp/1/SAMPLE.0/DB2/NODE0000/CATN0000/20240421/171717.001
and when I use docker with another instance - result for sample :
/tmp/1/SAMPLE.0.DB2.NODE0000.CATN0000.20240421171717.001
In docker I can restore but on server I get error:
SQL2542N No match for a database image file was found based on the source database alias "SAMPLE" and timestamp "20240421171717" provided.

Comment: I think problem in path because if run db2ckbkp -H ....
in first case i get
The proper image file name would be: /SAMPLE.0/DB2/NODE0000/CATN0000/20240421/171717.001
In second SAMPLE.0.DB2.NODE0000.CATN0000.20240421171717.001